# Cannot overwrite Wordpress file via FTP

Tags: php, wordpress, upload, ftp, filezilla

I'm currently working on a wordpress website, of which I'm trying to overwrite content-extensions.php with a new version. On uploading this it **appears** to work, the file transfer is successful. However, there is no change in the browser even after refreshing and clearing the cache. I've also ensured that there are no plugin's caching within wordpress, and file permissions are what they should be within FileZilla.

Here's the odd bit.

If I go into theme editor, and locate content-extensions.php I can see the changes that I've made in the source code. For whatever reason they're just not appearing in the browser.

I'd be really grateful if someone could point me in the right direction for this one, as I haven't a pickle.

Many thanks.

Comment: Is the browser called _Internet Explorer_? Have you tried checking in other browser?

Comment: I've tried both Chrome and Firefox, tried another computer, seems to make no odds.

Comment: Maybe you could post the original and the changed file here. The code i mean... And maybe some screenshots of what you are seeying? I think you are just overlooking something really small. I do that all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Are you working with an extension or with a theme based function?

If it's an extension, remember to activate it, i often forget that, i upload code, see it in the extension manager but forget to activate it.

If it's in the theme, are you sure you are using the right theme and not the basic one?

Comment: Hi there. This is just a theme based function, I'm just trying to insert a simple div tag. I'm also certain that I'm editing the correct file. The plot thickens.

Comment: I am seeing a lot of similar questions relating to filezilla and WordPress. What I have found is that oftentimes the theme and WordPress itself override changes made by the author. They have a mind of their own, so to speak. I wish I could offer more constructive and specific help.

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't shed any light on why it's actually happening but I've had that before and just deleted the file and uploaded the new one rather than trying to overwrite it.

Comment: Unfortunately I've tried that and it makes no difference. Thanks for the suggestion anyway.